# pwm-backlight driver not being probed in u-boot

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot, device-tree

I'm trying to get my PWM working on a custom am33x board (same beagle-bone black target). For some reason I don't see the `pwm-backlight` driver being probed and thus no PWM as indicated on my scope. Here are my relevant source files:

dts snippet:

```
/dts-v1/;

#include "am33xx.dtsi"
#include <dt-bindings/interrupt-controller/irq.h>

/ {
    model = "test";
    compatible = "ti,am33xx";

    chosen {
        stdout-path = &uart0;
    };

    backlight: backlight {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "pwm-backlight";
        pwms = <&ehrpwm1 0 10000 0>;

        brightness-levels = <0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 99>;
        default-brightness-level = <6>;
    };
};

&am33xx_pinmux {
    ehrpwm1_pins: pinmux-ehrpwm1-pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x848, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE6)    /* gpmc_a2.ehrpwm1a */
        >;
    };
};
&ehrpwm1 {
    u-boot,dm-spl;
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&ehrpwm1_pins>;
};
```

defconfig

```
CONFIG_DM=y
CONFIG_CMD_DM=y
CONFIG_DM_VIDEO=y
CONFIG_DM_PWM=y
CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_PWM=y
```

pwm-backlight driver info

```
config BACKLIGHT_PWM
    bool "Generic PWM based Backlight Driver"
    depends on DM_VIDEO && DM_PWM
    default y
    help
      If you have a LCD backlight adjustable by PWM, say Y to enable
      this driver.
      This driver can be use with "simple-panel" and
      it understands the standard device tree
      (leds/backlight/pwm-backlight.txt)
```

(linux version)
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/leds/backlight/pwm-backlight.txt

and when I interrupt u-boot and use `dm tree` you can see that its not probed. Why?

```
=> dm tree
 Class     Index  Probed  Driver                Name
-----------------------------------------------------------
 root         0  [ + ]   root_driver           root_driver
 simple_bus   0  [ + ]   generic_simple_bus    |-- ocp
 simple_bus   1  [   ]   generic_simple_bus    |   |-- l4_wkup@44c00000
 simple_bus   2  [   ]   generic_simple_bus    |   |   |-- prcm@200000
 simple_bus   3  [   ]   generic_simple_bus    |   |   `-- scm@210000
 syscon       0  [   ]   syscon                |   |       `-- scm_conf@0
 gpio         0  [   ]   gpio_omap             |   |-- gpio@44e07000
 gpio         1  [   ]   gpio_omap             |   |-- gpio@4804c000
 gpio         2  [   ]   gpio_omap             |   |-- gpio@481ac000
 gpio         3  [   ]   gpio_omap             |   |-- gpio@481ae000
 serial       0  [ + ]   omap_serial           |   |-- serial@44e09000
 mmc          0  [ + ]   omap_hsmmc            |   |-- mmc@481d8000
 timer        0  [ + ]   omap_timer            |   |-- timer@48040000
 timer        1  [   ]   omap_timer            |   |-- timer@48042000
 timer        2  [   ]   omap_timer            |   |-- timer@48044000
 timer        3  [   ]   omap_timer            |   |-- timer@48046000
 timer        4  [   ]   omap_timer            |   |-- timer@48048000
 timer        5  [   ]   omap_timer            |   |-- timer@4804a000
 misc         0  [ + ]   ti-musb-wrapper       |   `-- usb@47400000
 usb          0  [ + ]   ti-musb-peripheral    |       `-- usb@47401000
 eth          0  [ + ]   usb_ether             |           `-- usb_ether
 backlight    0  [   ]   pwm_backlight         `-- backlight
```

Comment: Is the displayed defconfig the u-boot one or the linux one?  Welcome at SO

Comment: It's the u-boot one

Comment: @newuser9370479 did you finally solve this ??